# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QuerySet'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm working from [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html) as a guide. Their SignupForm is very similar to mine, but I'm receiving an `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QuerySet'` error when I try to add the ManyToMany. (This is just the first step in what will eventually be several user types, so using `is_xyz` type Booleans on the MyUser class is not a long-term solution):

**models.py**

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        # Does the user have a specific permission?
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        # "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users_myuser'
        verbose_name = 'MyUser'


class ApplicationUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class AdminUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    destination = models.ManyToManyField(Destination, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class GatekeeperPlusSuperCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = CharField(label="Password", widget=PasswordInput)
    password2 = CharField(label="Password confirmation", widget=PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email',)

    destination = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Destination.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                             required=True)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            msg = "Passwords don't match"
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password mismatch")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(GatekeeperPlusSuperCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()

        admin_user = AdminUser.objects.create(user=user)
        admin_user.destination.add(self.cleaned_data["destination"])

        return admin_user
```

I get the error on the line `admin_user.destination.add(self.cleaned_data["destination"])`
. When I've tried `print(self.cleaned_data["destination"])` it does indeed show that it's a QuerySet, but why?

How can I get the value out of `destination = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Destination.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=True)` to save it as the ManyToManyField?

Comment: Can you post the  *full* traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `destination` allows you to select *multiple* values, so it is not a single object, but multiple.

You can however easily fix this with *sequence unpacking*:

```
admin_user.destination.add(*self.cleaned_data["destination"])
#                          ^
```

We thus put an asterisk (`*`) in front of the argument. Such that the elements in the `QuerySet` are unpacked, and passed as separate elements to the `.add(..)` function.

> **Note**: after reading the article, it turns out that the authors used sequence unpacking as well.

Note that Django has support for saving many-to-many relations with the [**`save_m2m`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) function.